# Output error redirection (about stderr)

Tags: c, logging, output, stderr

Where can I redirect my output error log when `stderr` is not available?

Comment: To a file?? To stdout?  What is your platform?

Comment: I am currently on linux-mint.

Comment: Is there any other system output that i can write on ? (sorry for double posting)

Comment: Mainly `stdout` or `stderr` are the same. So why isn't `stderr` available?

Comment: Could you give an example of a situation where `stderr` is not available?

Comment: No i don't, I just ear about that. But anyway there is no security in case of stderr cannot be available ? (by unavailable i mean that we cannot write on stderr)

Comment: You can use [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog)

Comment: @FabianleMaux, you're overthinking this.  C promises `stderr` to you, so it's perfectly reasonable to use it.  It is possible for your program (or any other) to be started with its `stderr` closed, but that's not your problem, it's the problem of whoever starts the program.  It's also possible to start your program with its `stdin` and `stdout` closed -- are you going to seek alternative to those, too?

Comment: You can open (create) a log file in an appropriate location and arrange that standard error goes to that file — [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) are most critical, and perhaps
[`close()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html).  Note that if standard error is closed, then it is quite likely that `open()` will return file descriptor 2 (standard error, `STDERR_FILENO`) — unless either standard input or standard output is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog)
                    – LPs